# How to end android Subscription when a certain condition is met?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I have a dictionary android app where a user purchases a subscription after the user queries a certain number of words suppose say 1000, I want the subscription to end, do I need a server to verify this? google play console does not seem to have this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subscription is for a certain period of time, and you cannot cancel it early.  Even if the user cancels the subscription, that only cancels the auto renew, and the subscription actually remains active until it expires.  If you want the user to buy a certain number of searches, then use a consumable product.  After purchase, record the purchase server-side and consume the product.  Then deduct as appropriate when the user takes actions.